# Why Netrw use rcp internally when I use scp protocol

Tags: netrw

I want to use netrw to edit remote files on my vps. Unfortunately, when I enter

```
vim scp://cydiater_server:~/demo/sol.cpp
```

and try to save something with `:w` Vim prompts me with

```
:!rcp  '/var/folders/74/flchcrkd4yx4d553byw606sr0000gn/T/vNVVwLF/0' 'scp://cydiater_server:~/demo/sol.cpp'
zsh:1: command not found: rcp
```

which seems that I don't have `rcp` in my host. But what I'm using is `scp`, why vim needs to use `rcp`?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @BLayer thanks, problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one thing caught my eye looking at this: the SCP path used when launching vim doesn't match paths shown in the netrw docs. For instance under `:h netrw-url`...

```
scp://[user@]host/path
```

And as `:h netrw-path` explains a little later

> Paths to files are generally user-directory relative for most
> protocols. Examples:
>
> `vim scp://user@host/somefile`
>
> `vim scp://user@host/subdir1/subdir2/somefile`

Given the possibility that your use of a non-standard path format may be throwing off netrw when you try to save, I suggest opening the file with:

```
vim scp://cydiater_server/demo/sol.cpp
```

or

```
vim scp://yourusername@cydiater_server/demo/sol.cpp
```

(I believe which one you choose depends on how authentication is set up.)

---

FYI, to use an absolute path, rooted at `/`, you use a double slash after the hostname like so

```
vim scp://user@host//foo/bar
```